# bootstrap 3 CSS Background Image not shown in printed preview

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I want to watermark background images and print the data with watermark images. I had watermark in div without print preview. When I use print dialog from browser, watermark image will not shown. I used bootstrap 3 framework.
My code is given below.

```
<div class="id-container"></div>
```

Here is css:

```
.id-container{
   background: url('public/images/boat_trans.jpg') no-repeat center;
}
@media print{
   *{-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}
}
```

Comment: Did you select *Print Background Graphics* in your browser’s print settings?

Comment: yes. i select print background graphics

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

adding `!important` at the end solved the problem for me.

```
.id-container{
   background: url('public/images/boat_trans.jpg') no-repeat center !important;
}
```